# Holder class (Having some objects references) compile error: 'Can not be referenced -- it is a deletted funciton'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I need a "holder" class. It is supposed to store objects references.

Like: holder.A = a; // Gets a reference!

Sample code bellow including the compiler error:

```
class A
{
};

class Holder
{
public:
    A& MyA; // I want to store a reference.
};

int main()
{
    A testA;
    Holder holder; // Compiler error: the default constructor of "Holder" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
    holder.A = testA; // I was hopping to get testA reference.
}
```

Comment: References cannot be reseated. You must initialize them at construction. `Holder holder{testA};` But why do you want this anyway? The class will not actually hold the object. It will just reference it. (Lots of chances here that you are going about solving your actual problem in the wrong way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that since your class `Holder` has a reference data member `MyA`, its default constructor `Holder::Holder()` will be implicitly deleted.

This can be seen from [Deleted implicitly-declared default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) that says:

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted (since C++11) default constructor for class T is undefined (until C++11)defined as **deleted (since C++11) if any of the following is true**:
>
> - `T` has a member of reference type without a default initializer (since C++11).

(emphasis mine)

---

To **solve** this you can provide a constructor to initialize the reference data member `MyA` as shown below:

```
class A
{
};

class Holder
{
public:
    A& MyA; 
    //provide constructor that initialize the MyA in the constructor initializer list
    Holder( A& a): MyA(a)//added this ctor
    {
        
    }
};

int main()
{
    A testA;
    Holder holder(testA); //pass testA
    
}
```

[Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/sS03cOFzZ)

Comment: Nice, got it. How can I add a default (empty) constructor?

Comment: @Pedro77 If you provide an empty default constructor(without providing a separate ctor that initializes `MyA`) then the program won't compile and give error that you've not initialized the data member `MyA`. See [DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/duZJJaV6b) of the error. So we must provide a ctor that initializes the reference data member `MyA`.

Comment: Holder( A& a): MyA(a) // ok, added this. But I want to have a Holder() that creates the objects and calls the constructor with parameters.

Comment: @Pedro77 Note that if you create a temporary object and use that temporary object to bound to `MyA` then the temporary will be destroyed after its scope end. So the reference will be become a dangling reference. My recommendation would be to use the constructor `Holder(A&)` itself without having a default ctor.

Answer (score 0):

References (`MyA`) should be bound to something and can't be empty, since you don't tell what it should bind to, the default constructor is ill formed.

> prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
> prog.cc:23:12: error: use of deleted function 'Holder::Holder()'
> 23 |     Holder holder; // Compiler error: the default constructor of "Holder" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
> |            ^~~~~~
> prog.cc:14:7: note: 'Holder::Holder()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
> 14 | class Holder

You need to add a constructor specifying how to initialized `MyA`

```
Holder(A &obj):MyA(obj){}
```

and then create holder objects

```
A testA;
Holder holder(testA);
```